# Why can I still drag my custom view even if I don't touch the view on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm adding a custom view dynamically to a FrameLayout. The custom view overrides the onTouchEvent method and the custom view also overrides the onDraw method to redraw the bitmap correctly. Everything is working fine except that if I touch outside the custom view and I start dragging, it still drags my custom view as well. This is what I have:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:background="@drawable/balloons"
    tools:context="com.blah.test.SomeActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

And I'm adding my custom view like so in my SomeActivity.java:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stencil_tigerclaw);
parentView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.custom_view_container);
stencil = new CustomImageView(this, bitmap, parentView);
parentView.addView(stencil);
```

Here is my CustomImageView:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private float scale = 1;
    private float angle = 0;

    private Matrix transform = new Matrix();
    private Vector2D position = new Vector2D();
    private TouchManager touchManager = new TouchManager(2);

    private boolean isInitialized = false;

    private FrameLayout parentView;

    public CustomImageView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, FrameLayout parentView) {
        super(context);

        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.width = bitmap.getWidth();
        this.height = bitmap.getHeight();
        this.parentView = parentView;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        try {
            touchManager.update(event);

            if (touchManager.getPressCount() == 1) {
                position.add(touchManager.moveDelta(0));    
            }
            else {
                if (touchManager.getPressCount() == 2) {
                    Vector2D current = touchManager.getVector(0, 1);
                    Vector2D previous = touchManager.getPreviousVector(0, 1);
                    float currentDistance = current.getLength();
                    float previousDistance = previous.getLength();

                    if (previousDistance != 0) {
                        scale *= currentDistance / previousDistance;
                    }

                    angle -= Vector2D.getSignedAngleBetween(current, previous);
                }
            }

            invalidate();
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            // Do something...
        }
        return true;
    }

    public float getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (!isInitialized) {
            position.set(parentView.getWidth()/2, parentView.getHeight()/2);
            isInitialized = true;
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        transform.reset();
        transform.postTranslate(-width / 2.0f, -height / 2.0f);
        transform.postRotate(getDegreesFromRadians(angle));
        transform.postScale(scale, scale);
        transform.postTranslate(position.getX(), position.getY());

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, transform, paint);
    }
```

and finally here is my TouchManager class:

```
public class TouchManager {

    private final int maxNumberOfTouchPoints;

    private final Vector2D[] points;
    private final Vector2D[] previousPoints;

    public TouchManager(final int maxNumberOfTouchPoints) {
        this.maxNumberOfTouchPoints = maxNumberOfTouchPoints;

        points = new Vector2D[maxNumberOfTouchPoints];
        previousPoints = new Vector2D[maxNumberOfTouchPoints];
    }

    public boolean isPressed(int index) {
        return points[index] != null;
    }

    public int getPressCount() {
        int count = 0;
        for(Vector2D point : points) {
            if (point != null)
                ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public Vector2D moveDelta(int index) {

        if (isPressed(index)) {
            Vector2D previous = previousPoints[index] != null ? previousPoints[index] : points[index];
            return Vector2D.subtract(points[index], previous);
        }
        else {
            return new Vector2D();
        }
    }

    private static Vector2D getVector(Vector2D a, Vector2D b) {
        if (a == null || b == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("can't do this on nulls");

        return Vector2D.subtract(b, a);
    }

    public Vector2D getPoint(int index) {
        return points[index] != null ? points[index] : new Vector2D();
    }

    public Vector2D getPreviousPoint(int index) {
        return previousPoints[index] != null ? previousPoints[index] : new Vector2D();
    }

    public Vector2D getVector(int indexA, int indexB) {
        return getVector(points[indexA], points[indexB]);
    }

    public Vector2D getPreviousVector(int indexA, int indexB) {
        if (previousPoints[indexA] == null || previousPoints[indexB] == null)
            return getVector(points[indexA], points[indexB]);
        else
            return getVector(previousPoints[indexA], previousPoints[indexB]);
    }

    public void update(MotionEvent event) {
        int actionCode = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            int index = event.getAction() >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
            previousPoints[index] = points[index] = null;
        }
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i < maxNumberOfTouchPoints; ++i) {
                if (i < event.getPointerCount()) {
                    int index = event.getPointerId(i);

                    Vector2D newPoint = new Vector2D(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));

                    if (points[index] == null)
                        points[index] = newPoint;
                    else {
                        if (previousPoints[index] != null) {
                            previousPoints[index].set(points[index]);
                        }
                        else {
                            previousPoints[index] = new Vector2D(newPoint);

                        }

                        if (Vector2D.subtract(points[index], newPoint).getLength() < 64)
                            points[index].set(newPoint);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    previousPoints[i] = points[i] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, when you create a custom view, you need to overwrite

```
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
```

to set the width and height properly.

Comment: This sets the image to the proper width and height but the image can't be dragged everywhere on the screen, it can only be drawn from 0,0 and the image width and height.